# Young Indoor Lychee Trees: Do I prune?

Tags: leaves, pruning, nutrients, lychee

I germinated some Lychee seeds when it was really hot and humid in NYC this summer (~13 weeks ago). They grew really quickly and healthily until mid October when a new layer of leaves sprouted. The new ones struggled to grow and older leaves started to get brown spots. I thought it was either due to lower light levels or lack of plant nutrition. I bought an LED UV light and put some miracle grow plant food in their pots and now they seem to be doing ok. See pictures:[image]

Question:

Does this look like a nutrition issue that i have solved or does it look like disease? should I expect the brown leaves to get healthy again? Should i prune them off or just leave them where they are? I have no gardening experience. No idea when pruning is required. Any background info on looking after a young tree would be great!

Comment: You do realize that (1) these need a tropical climate, and (2) it's a tree that grows 50 to 100 feet tall, not a house plant? There is no way it is going to be happy in a tiny pot like your picture.

Comment: I do realise that.. they are in those large pots so i can keep them indoors and in a replicated tropical environment for the winter, not for their life.

Comment: Also.. lychee trees top out at around 40 feet.

Comment: Whether they reach 40 feet or 50 feet is just quibbling. It's more relevant that most trees grown from seed start with the root system growing faster than the stems above ground. That makes sense, since they need to anchor themselves, get a good nutrient and water supply, and survive accidental damage. In the wild, shoots get trampled or eaten, but roots don't get interfered with so much. Starting trees off in pots doesn't allow the roots to develop that way. If you must grow them in pots, at least *fill* the pot with compost - the ones in your picture look only half full to me.